# VSCode Debug C++: Why does the flow not stop at breakpoint?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

> VSCode Version:1.3.1
>
> OS Version:Ubuntu 14.04

I debug a C++ project on Ubuntu 14.04. I run cmake to produce an executable file and setting VSCode config file. When I press F5 to debug, the program runs well, but it doesn't stop at breakpoint!

my source code is in `${workspaceRoot}/InfiniTAM`

executable file is in `${workspaceRoot}/build`

My config file:

```
tasjs.json

    {
"version": "0.1.0",    
"command": "echo",    
"isShellCommand": true,    
"args": ["InfiniTAM!"],    
"showOutput": "always"    
}

launch.json    
{
    "version": "0.2.0",    
    "configurations": [    
        {    
            "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",    
            "type": "cppdbg",    
            "request": "launch",
            "launchOptionType": "Local",    
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",    
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/InfiniTAM",    
            "args": ["Teddy/calib.txt", "Teddy/Frames/%04i.ppm","Teddy/Frames/%04i.pgm"],    
            "stopAtEntry": false,    
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build",    
            "environment": [],    
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Feel free to tag my answer as solution, if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 49):

Watch out, how you compile your code:
In order to be able to debug you need to compile e.g. with `g++` with the flag `-g`.

Comment: This information should be plastered on the VS Code debugger page... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have had this same problem for a while and am now able to write a working configuration which works universally for all C and CPP programs and you don't need to change anything during execution.

- **Install Code-Runner Extention**.
- Paste the configuration given below into your **`settings.json`** file.

  ```
   {
     "code-runner.executorMap": {

      "javascript": "nodejs",
      "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
      "c": "cd $dir && gcc -g \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && $dir\"$fileNameWithoutExt\"",
      "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -g \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && $dir\"$fileNameWithoutExt\"",
      "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
      "php": "php",
      "python": "python3",
      "perl": "perl",
      "ruby": "ruby",
      "go": "go run",
      "lua": "lua",
      "groovy": "groovy",
      "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
      "bat": "cmd /c",
      "shellscript": "bash",
      "fsharp": "fsi",
      "csharp": "scriptcs",
      "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
      "typescript": "ts-node",
      "coffeescript": "coffee",
      "scala": "scala",
      "swift": "swift",
      "julia": "julia",
      "crystal": "crystal",
      "ocaml": "ocaml",
      "r": "Rscript",
      "applescript": "osascript",
      "clojure": "lein exec",
      "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
      "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
      "racket": "racket",
      "ahk": "autohotkey",
      "autoit": "autoit3",
      "kotlin": "cd $dir && kotlinc $fileName -include-runtime -d $fileNameWithoutExt.jar && java -jar $fileNameWithoutExt.jar",
      "dart": "dart",
      "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
      "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
      "haskell": "runhaskell",
      "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run"
  }
  }
  ```
- Paste the below code in **`launch.json`** by clicking the settings symbol in the debugging panel (present at top left).

  ```
  {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "(gdb) Launch",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": true,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
              {
                  "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                  "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                  "ignoreFailures": true
              }
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- After this When ever you press ctrl+Alt+N it compiles and executes and you can see the output in the output panel.
- When You Press F5 after selecting the right Task ( choose (gdb)Launch ). It will start the debugging with working break points and stuff.

Comment: This helped me realize I was missing the `-g` arg in the compile command, and how to use filename with gdb.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that

> "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"

is not right because "cwd" should contain the path to your source code. Otherwise breakpoints cannot be mapped from source code to your program.

Did you try to change it to

> "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/InfiniTAM"

?

Currently I am also having debugging issues with VSCode and C which could also relate to your problem. Therefore I may update my post soon with a link to my issue.